# Laravel Queues in aws lambda

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I use laravel for developing backend part.

I created lambda function which send emails.

But I want to send mails using **laravel Queues**.

Locally I can configure supervisor which will process new jobs as they are pushed onto the queue.

The main problem how to configure supervisor in lambda function.

I know about **aws sqs**. But is there any other way to use queues in aws?

Answer (score 2):

Supervisor is a service running on a server which, in the case of Laravel Queues, sets up a number of continuously running PHP processes which poll a central queue of jobs (Redis, SQS, etc).

It sounds more like you need a queue managment system to run your supervisor service (or equivalent) and the `Job`s themeselves will then run your AWS Lambda functions.

i.e. **Supervisor runs jobs that create Lambda functions** rather than **Lambda functions setup Supervisor which runs jobs**